# Are fully custom SLDS themes possible in communities?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, slds, theme-branding

Bootstrap has a "themes" mechanism where a HTML page using the Bootstrap class names can be presented using many different colour schemes, fonts, spacing etc. For example:

[image: Cyborg]

or

[image: Simplex]

and it is possible to [create your own theme](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/) to match your own branding.

Has anyone explored this for SLDS? I guess there are at least two parts to the problem:

- Generating the CSS starting from different design tokens
- Incorporating the CSS at runtime

The context here is in a customer community. Colours and fonts can be chosen there: is that the limit of what can be changed?